# copy two files at a time

Tags: command-line, files, cp

What to do if I want to copy two file at a time using command ? let's say I have one folder named `ABC`  and files are

```
mno.txt
xyz.txt
abcd.txt
qwe.txt and so on (100 no. of files)
```

Now I want to cp `mno.txt` and `xyz.txt` at a time . How can I do this ?

Comment: Copy to where? To `ABC`?

Comment: To different folder .

Comment: Assuming that you actually want to copy several files at the same time, and not just after each other, could you say something about the reason _why_ you want to do this? If it is to improve performance, it probably will not work.

Comment: My aim is to make my work speedy.I am dealing with asterisk and while making config files cp generally I have only two files to give attention.So every time I seperatly copy that two files.So I want that two files at another latest folder at a time only for saving time , else separately cp of that two files is my current scenario.

Comment: If the filesystem is sitting on a spinning platter hd (instead of ssd) then copying sequentially will be faster as the heads won't need to seek between the two different source and destination files. If on a RAID then things are more complicated as the files can be on (or even split over) several drives.

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you want to `cp` files into a directory, you can use the usual syntax for `cp`:

```
cp mno.txt xyz.txt destination_directory
```

Or use brace expansion for brevity:

```
cp {mno,xyz}.txt destination_directory
```

For the sake of clarity, it is better to use the `-t` (`--target-directory`) option of `cp`, this is GNU-ism:

```
cp -t destination_directory {mno,xyz}.txt
```

---

Just to note, if you want to `cp` the contents of multiple files with one go of `cp`, you can't. `cp` deals with one file at a time when copying contents of one file to another.

Comment: Disregard the previous comment. I understand now you're referring to  basically simultaneous copying of files. That indeed cannot be done, at least not with `cp`. My script also does each file one by one. Simultaneous copying would require a very sophisticated algorithm, at least on the level of TCP algorithm

Comment: @Serg: Very sophisticated? As in `for fname in {mno,xyz}.txt ; do cp "${fname}" target_directory & done` ? The `&` launches command in background, which essentially means "run them all at once". Note that since you're copying to the same destination (and over the same channel), the speed of simultaneous copy would probably be the same as serial copy, minus overhead. __TL;DR:__ It's easy - but pointless.

Comment: @Piskvor well, that's essentially creating multiple processes in background. Good approach, no doubt ! But what i am referring to is processing multiple files from the same one. That's also what heemayl alluded to - cp iterates over command line arguments, which is an obvious solution. OP hasn't clearly stated if that's what they want.

Comment: @Piskvor The thing you are doing _clumsily_ in a loop `cp` is doing natively. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Also, sending command in background is not necessarily simultaneous to multi-threading, also there is looping overhead involved.

Comment: For the sake of clarify, one can also simply add a `/` to `destination_directory`, and there is no confusion.

Comment: @heemayl: I'm aware that cp can do that sequentially; was reacting to Serg's comment that it *can't* be done in parallel - note my observation that it's essentially pointless, as the bottleneck would be *in* the FS, not in "how quickly can you throw requests *at* the FS."

Answer (score 3):

Use `cp -t destination_dir/  file1 file2` syntax.

Example:

```
bash-4.3$ ls dir1
file1  file2  file3
bash-4.3$ ls dir2/
bash-4.3$ cp -t dir2/  dir1/file1 dir1/file2
bash-4.3$ ls dir2
file1  file2
```

#### Addition to original answer.

The uses who like to play with python , may be interested in the following script, which allows copying arbitrary number of files specified on command line, with last argument being the destination.

Demo:

```
bash-4.3$ ls dir1
file1  file2  file3
bash-4.3$ ls dir2
bash-4.3$ ./copyfiles.py dir1/file1 dir1/file2 dir2
bash-4.3$ ls dir2
file1  file2
```

Script itself:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from shutil import copyfile
from os import path
from sys import argv

new_dir = path.realpath(argv[-1])
for f in argv[1:-1]:
    base = path.basename(f)
    orig_file = path.realpath(f)
    new_file = path.join(new_dir,base)
    copyfile(orig_file,new_file)
```

Comment: What does the script do that `cp` doesn't?

Comment: @CarstenS it does exactly the same thing :) that's the whole point - provide alternative approach, different perspective on the same task.

Comment: Somebody downvoted my answer.By definition, downvote means that answer isn't useful.  I'd like to point out, that my answer provides a proper solution of using `cp -t DEST FILE1 FILE2 . . . ` and extra material as well. Just because you don't like alternative solutions or extra material added to answers, doesn't make my answer not useful  :)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to copy them at the same location (not to a new directory) to make backups, (for example), you can use a very small `for` loop to copy them with new names (here adding a `.bak` extension)

```
for f in {mno,xyz}.txt; do cp -- "$f" "$f".bak; done
```

`{`brace expansion`}` is the most succinct way to specify the particular files in your example, but you can use any suitable shell wildcards/globbing, or list out the files if necessary: `for f in foo bar baz;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
cp {mno,xyz}.txt /path/to/destination
```

Or if you need all .txt files:

```
cp {*}.txt /path/to/destination
```